# Does Ktor support Kotlin/WASM for web development?

Tags: webassembly, ktor

I'm currently exploring the potential of using Kotlin with WebAssembly (WASM) for web development, and I'm particularly interested in leveraging the Ktor framework due to its elegant design and ease of use. I'm curious to know if there's any official support or ongoing community efforts to integrate Ktor with Kotlin/WASM.

Could someone please clarify whether Ktor has native support for Kotlin/WASM or if there are any known workarounds or community contributions that facilitate this integration?

Comment: Work is currently underway on the Ktor WASM client.